# How can I open WP rich editor within colorbox in the front end?

Tags: wp-editor

I have a site on which I've created a form to add new posts. The form opens in colorbox and I want it to contain a rich editor. I've added this code:

```
<?php
$args = array('textarea_rows' => 15, 'media_buttons' => false);
wp_editor( '', 'editor_content_1', $args );
?>
```

instead of a textarea. The WP editor is displayed but the rich editor buttons does not appear and it doesn't work well.

You can see the actual site [here - link directly to that element](http://test.hannitcohen.co.il/newsgeek/#add_new_discussion). The "colorbox" opens when pressing the `+ Add New` button

This is the Button, it's around 2/3 of the page

[image]

Comment: Guess you're missing scripts or admin files. Scripts could be `wpdialogs` or `wpdialogs-popup` (both the handles used inside `wp_enqueue_script`. Btw: What's `+ Add New` in Hebrew?

Comment: Man! I had to translate the site, then search for it. Better update your post with an image to show ***where exactly one has to click***... `Only geeks can create a new discussion! To become a certified geek, register your account.` is the message I get. Don't tell me I need to register to test that? Hm?

Comment: Fixed that. sorry

Comment: And where's the screenshot? Not everyone speak Hebrew...

Comment: Added these JS files. no good :-(